# How to create a multifield programmatically without using features

Tags: entities

I have a custom module that I am working on that uses a couple of custom content types. I am trying to keep the module as self-contained as possible and thus far I've been able to create my content types using field_create_field() and field_create_instance(). However, I've just hit a point where it would be really nice to be able to implement a multifield in a content type, and that's where I get stuck. I have example feature exports to look at, but I'd rather not use features if possible.

Any help would be appreciated if either someone knows how to implement a multifield in the .install file of a custom module, or if anyone can explain that this is simply a bad approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say multifield are you referring to some other module that provides a "multifield" or a custom field that you want to implement that is a composite of multiple fields?

Comment: If you want unlimited field entries, you need to set `cardinality => -1` in your field instance. Let me know if you need an example for that.

Comment: I am looking for help implementing a form with an instance of the multifield module (https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield). It allows you to treat two or more fields as a single field so that setting cardinality covers the grouped fields as a single unit. An example would be if you were looking to create a form with multiple URLs where you would enter the URL and anchor text as a single item.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?  Need to do the same thing myself....

Comment: For the project in question I had originally tried to encapsulate all the planned functionality into a single module, but shortly after posting I decided that it was too complicated for that and created it as a distro instead, meaning features were no longer off limits. That said, if I had to approach this now my guess is that I would go through the effort of creating a custom field/widget (multifield is basically a shortcut to do this through the ui) and implement that instead. Depending on your needs features may be the best approach, or custom fields might work as well.